# Show Firebase notification only if user wants it to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've set an option via SharedPreferences to show notifications only if the user wants it to. How can I implement this? Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.i("FIREBASE", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    if (ALLOW_NOTIFICATIONS){
        //show notification
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't handle on your application, because it handled automatically by Firebase SDK.

So the tricky way that you can use is using **send topic** on firebase.

for example if user want to receive notification just subscribe the topic with this code :

`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("AllowNotification");`

and if user won't to receive the notif jus unsubscribe it.

`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("AllowNotification");`